# What are the Android 4.0.x Ice Cream Sandwich Easter Eggs?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, settings, easter-egg

I heard that there are some Easter eggs hidden in ice cream sandwich version.

How can I view the Easter eggs hidden in my android device and how can I view them? I'm using Android 4 ICS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to `Settings->About Phone` (this is the last menu item in the settings menu) and find the version number menu item in the menu.

[image: Settings]

[image: Find the android version number]

**1. Find the android**

Quickly tap the android version number several times and an android will appear on your screen:

[image: ICS android]

**2. Find the *nyan-droid***

Press and hold the android n the screen and it will grow. Keep holding it and at the end a set of androids wearing ice cream sandwiches will fly across your screen, like so:

[image: nyan-droids]

**Enjoy!!**

Comment: Hey! This works in JB too, except that the stuff is Jellybean themed :D

Comment: Did not know about the second one, very nice! :)

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi I think it works with every version!