# Press android version thrice took me to another screen which shows big Jellybean logo!

Tags: settings, samsung-galaxy-nexus, 4.2-jelly-bean, easter-egg

When i pressed *settings*> *About phone* >*Android version* thrice quickly, it took me to another screen which displays *Android version with Red  Logo*. I wonder this behavior is common in all Android Flavors. I have galaxy Nexus with Jellybean 4.2.2

Comment: See also: [What are the Android 4.0.x Ice Cream Sandwich Easter Eggs?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35517/), and [Android 4.2: How to get the Easter Egg, a new daydream, and Developer options?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34697/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its called Easter egg. All android versions contain same feature. You just hold that screen for 2 sec, and some more will be displayed.

[image]

[image]

**JellyBean**
[image]

[image]

**Ice cream Sandwich**

[image]

**Honeycomb**

[image]

**Gingerbread**

[image]